# Trying to install JIBX m2e connector in eclipse- Getting install error

Tags: m2eclipse, jibx, maven-jibx

Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.

Software currently installed: m2e connector for JiBX 1.2.3.201107241325 (org.jibx.m2e.feature.feature.group 1.2.3.201107241325)

Missing requirement: m2e connector for JiBX 1.2.3.201107241325 (org.jibx.m2e.plugin 1.2.3.201107241325) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.m2e.jdt [1.0.0,1.1.0)' but it could not be found

Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: m2e connector for JiBX 1.2.3.201107241325 (org.jibx.m2e.feature.feature.group 1.2.3.201107241325)

To: org.jibx.m2e.plugin [1.2.3.201107241325]

Comment: having the same error

Comment: But looks like no one uses this these days.. :(

Comment: There is another m2e connector labeled (juno), but it fails on another unsatisfied dependency. It seems these plugins have not been maintained since May 2013, and no longer work with current Java/Eclipse environments.